# Sphinx add_config_value not adding variable

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, django-sphinx

Trying to add a simple true/false value per the docs here:

http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/ifconfig.html

In my `conf.py` file:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.ifconfig']

# Custom variables
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('responsiveenabled', True, True)
```

In my `grids.rst` file (a page to describe how to set up a bootstrap grid), I have this:

```
.. ifconfig:: responsiveenabled

Blah blah blah.
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
NameError: name 'responsiveenabled' is not defined
```

Do I need something after the `responsiveenabled`, like "in (...)"? I'd like to keep it agnostic to which version of the docs I'm writing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `conf.py` file should be:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.ifconfig']

# Custom variables
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('responsiveenabled', True, True)

responsiveenabled = True
```

I know it is supposed to be a default value, but I could not get it work 
without init.

then you can use

```
.. ifconfig:: responsiveenabled

   text included if the config variable is set

text always included
```